# Interesting issue with UICollectionView reloadData

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

When dealing with a `UICollectionView` in my app I've ran into a strange problem related to reloading data. After lot's of debugging and analyzing logs I've come to the conclusion that if `reloadData` is immediately followed by `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` the dreaded error below is guaranteed to occur:

> Name: `NSInternalInconsistencyException` Reason: Invalid update: invalid
>   number of items in section 0. The number of items contained in an
>   existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of
>   items contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus
>   the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted)
>   ...

They only way for this to happen consistently is that internally the `UICollectionView` is still busy with `reloadData` when the call to `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` arrives. The fact that "`collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection`" is called twice in a row before the `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` completes seems to support this since that method is never called twice in a row in call other cases.

Has anyone seen similar behavior or can confirm my analysis or even suggest a proper workaround?

**Update**: Any yes I've made sure that all relevant invocations occur on the main thread.

**Update 2**: Since the reasoning behind getting into this situation at all has been questioned: I'm using Monotouch and the code in question is intended to keep generic .Net Collections firing [this event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction.aspx) into the appropriate calls to keep the UICollectionView bound to the collection in sync. When the source collection is cleared it reacts with a *Reset* action, followed by one or more *Add* actions when items get inserted into it which leads to the problem outlined above. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You either reload the whole thing, or you insert/remove items manually. Doing both doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Oliver Weichhold, If you are sure that is a bug, here's the link to [Apple bugreporter](https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/). There's also an option to [contact](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/) Apple engineers for a code-level support, I believe you have two prepaid tickets per year included in the developer program price.

Comment: As I understand it now, the framework sends some change notification - at this point it already updated the internal data source? Then you call reloadData, which updates the whole thing (incl. the new items already). If you now call insertItems..., you get an inconsistent state. If you insertItems..., you need to adjust your dataSource as well.

Comment: @Eiko Nope. The underlying collection sends a CollectionChanged event _after_ it has been updated. The Custom Data Source wrapping the collection correctly responds to all numberOfItemsInSection, cellForItemAtIndexPath etc. calls triggered by insertItemsAtIndexPaths. Only in this case where insertItemsAtIndexPaths immediately follows reloadData something goes wrong internally with the UICollectionView. I know that I'm not supposed to notify the collection view of data source changes before those changes happen and obey those rules.

Comment: You might want to show your complete code block here so that we can take a deeper look into it. I doubt that this is a bug on Apple's part; without code, we can only guess.

Comment: From reloadData documentation: "It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows"...

Comment: We ran into the same issue. We fixed it in various ways: you can perform the updates in a @syncronized way protectinc the critical properties that hold the data, you can use batchUpdates (this also worked), but really the cause of the crash was not related with synching (which could happen in your case too). Knowing the code that fetches and updates the collection will help.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` (`removeItemsAtIndexPaths` is analogous), you are telling your collectionview that its datasource now has more items available, and that it should insert these available items at the indexpaths you specify.

It checks your datasource whether that statement is true, and if it detects that the amount of old items plus the amount of items you say you inserted is not equal to the amount of new items, it says it can't do the update, as you lied about how many items you changed.

Now, what you are doing is you are telling your collectionview is that it should reload all its data from its datasource (with the new data) and right after that, you tell it you inserted x items. That is a false statement, as you just reloaded the collectionview, which updated its amount of items, and thus the amount of items before the update is equal to the amount of items after the update (you're not doing anything), and not increased by the amount of indexpaths you specified.

I hope you're still with me, because here's your solution:

Remove the `reloadData` before the `insertItemsAtIndexPaths`, as this breaks its assertions and will throw exceptions when incorrectly used. If you would like to reload the collectionview before inserting items, make sure you perform `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` right after you change the items in the datasource.

Read up on the documentation for this method [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/insertItemsAtIndexPaths:).